# Is JRebel necessary to run Maven?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, lift, jrebel

Greetings,

I am trying to start a scala/liftweb project for deployment on Google App Engine. To do this, i need to package it up as a .war using maven.

However, whenever I run the 'mvn' command, I am met with:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Applications/JRebel/jrebel.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Is there something wrong with my maven or do I need Jrebel? I see jrebel is not free which is why I am so surprised.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, JRebel is definitely *not* required to run Maven.

Answer (score 2):

As Matt mentioned, JRebel is not required to run Maven. However, ZeroTurnaround does offer a free version that works with Scala. You can get it here:

http://sales.zeroturnaround.com/

As for your error - it indicates you are trying to start the JVM as though you are using JRebel. What is the full Maven command you are running? What is in your MAVEN_OPTS environment variable? If either of them contain something like -noverify -javaagent:/Applications/JRebel/jrebel.jar, then that's your problem.

Comment: found it out just now and came back here to post it. you were exactly right though. I just was editing my config.fish and noticed:

Comment: set -x MAVEN_OPTS "-noverify -javaagent:/Applications/JRebel/jrebel.jar"

booyah!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason of the problem is a blank in the path of jrebel.jar
Make sure that there is no blank in the path like in "Program Files"